# Can not find a correct way to send axios post request to .NET backend API (FromBody)

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, .net, typescript, axios

Helllo,
I'm trying to send a post request to the following endpoint:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/admin/plebs/decision")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePlebsDecisions(
        [FromBody] IEnumerable<CreatePlebsDecisionsRequest> decisionsRequest)
```

The "CreatePlebsDecisionsRequest" looks as following:

```
public record CreatePlebsDecisionsRequest
{
    public required string AdminId { get; set; }
    public required string PlebId { get; init; }
    public required bool IsAccepted { get; init; }
}
```

However, when i send such a request (via axios)

```
// types
export type PlebsDecisionsRequests = {
  decisionsRequest: PlebDecision[];
};

export type PlebDecision = {
  plebId: string;
  isAccepted: boolean;
};
// calling code in component
const plebsDecisions = plebRequests.map((pr) => ({
      plebId: pr.plebId,
      isAccepted: pr.isAccepted,
    }));

    const request = {
      decisionsRequest: plebsDecisions,
    };
// the method itself
await makePlebsDecisions(request);
  const makePlebsDecisions = async (
    plebsDecisions: PlebsDecisionsRequests
  ): Promise<PlebRequestResponse> => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    const payload = JSON.stringify(plebsDecisions);

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('/admin/plebs/decision', payload);
// the post object in chome dev tools
{
    "decisionsRequest": [
        {
            "plebId": "8e694149-102c-4d23-9e43-3555b46b4c4b",
            "isAccepted": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I get the following error message back (from the api):

```
{
    "$": [
        "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DalaranApp.Contracts.Admins.Decisions.CreatePlebsDecisionsRequest]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."
    ],
    "decisionsRequest": [
        "The decisionsRequest field is required."
    ]
}
```

I can't seem to find a solution for this, any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, it looks as follows:

The request object should be changed to :

```
public record CreatePlebsDecisionsRequest
{
    public string? AdminId { get; set; }
    public string PlebId { get; init; }
    public bool IsAccepted { get; init; }
}
```

And here is the gamechanger: the controller should accept a LIST instead of IENUMERABLE (I have no idea why IEnumerable didn't work)

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/admin/plebs/decision")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePlebsDecisions(
    [FromBody] List<CreatePlebsDecisionsRequest> decisionsRequest)
```

After making those changes, everything works

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the backend from javascript:

```
params = new URLSearchParams({mode: "night", page : "2"});
```

From https://medium.com/swlh/urlsearchparams-in-javascript-df524f705317, this helped me a lot.